# Counting operations without null values in matrix multiplication in r

Tags: r, matrix, vector, multiplication

I have a vector a and matrix A

```
a = c(2,5,6)
b=cbind(c(2,7,0),c(3,0,11),c(99,0,0))
A = as.matrix(b)
```

I want to multiply a on matrix A and to get as the result vector which counts numbers of operations without nulls.For this example the answer should be :

```
2*2+5*7+6*0  (there are two operations without 0.So the answer is 2)
2*3+5*0+6*11 (there are two operations without 0.So the answer is 2)
2*99+5*0+6*0 (there is  one operation  without 0.So the answer is 1)
THe answer should be (2,2,1)
```

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
>  rowSums((t(A) * a)  !=0)
[1] 2 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

We multiple 'A' with 'a', convert it to a logical `matrix` by comparing whether the values are not equal to 0 and get the column sums of the logical columns

```
colSums((A * a) != 0)
#[1] 2 2 1
```

Note that

```
A * a
#    [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    4    6  198
#[2,]   35    0    0
#[3,]    0   66    0
```

and

```
t(A) * a
#    [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    4   14    0
#[2,]   15    0   55
#[3,]  594    0    0
```

The values in OP's post

```
2*2+5*7+6*0
```

matches with `A * a`

Based on the example, as there are no zero elements in 'a'

```
colSums(A != 0)
#[1] 2 2 1
```

---

or using `apply`

```
apply(A, 2, FUN = function(x) sum((x * a) != 0))
#[1] 2 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answers. 
I tried to work with vector also with nulls:

```
d= c(0,2,4,6)
b=cbind(c(2,7,0,7),c(3,0,11,9),c(99,0,0,2),c(9,0,0,2)) 
B= as.matrix(b)
```

Then I multyply vector d to matrix B

d*B

```
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
  [1,]    0    0    0    0
  [2,]   14    0    0    0
  [3,]    0   44    0    0
  [4,]   42   54   12   12
```

the last one is to summ numbers of columns without 0:

```
colSums((d*B)  !=0)
```

PROFIT!
final code is:

```
d= c(0,2,4,6)
b=cbind(c(2,7,0,7),c(3,0,11,9),c(99,0,0,2),c(9,0,0,2)) 
B= as.matrix(b)
colSums((d*B)  !=0)
```